# Mi app se ejecuta con lag

Tags: ios

He creado una app bastante sencilla y cuando la ejecuto, lo hace con un lag en el cambio de pantallas. Cuando pulso en un botón de configuración o cuando pulso en una celda para ver el detalle, el cambio de vista lo hace con un lag muy molesto.

¿Alguna idea de cuál puede ser el problema?

Podéis ver el problema en el siguiente vídeo: https://youtu.be/UBOq-23kFNg

El que quiera, puede ver el problema en su propia terminal, la app se llama "Lezo Ibilbideak"

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿los datos son cargados de local o remoto?

Comment: localmente y no tarda nada, lo tengo comprobado.

Comment: ¿Y los datos los consultas antes de mostrar el siguiente `viewController` o en el el `viewDidLoad` del nuevo `viewController`?

Comment: Por ejemplo en la pantalla de configuración, la de seleccionar el idioma, el 'viewDidLoad' esta vacio y en el 'viewWillAppear' le asigno un texto a dos label y el alpha a dos imagenes.

Comment: No, me refiero a los datos que se muestran en la pantalla, los que consultas de CoreData. Hay cierta diferencia entre cargarlos antes de la acción del botón y cargarlos en la pantalla donde los vas a mostrar... Podría ser el origen del problema.

Comment: Hola, perdón la tardanza en responder, el caso es que tenia lag hasta en las pantallas donde no usaba CoreData. Estoy rehaciendo la app, esta vez con una plantilla "Empty" y comprobando el lag según voy haciendola y en algunas pantallas ya no tiene lag. Espero terminar de rehacerla entre hoy y mañana y te comento como va.

Comment: ¡Perfecto! Cualquier duda avisa...

Comment: Creo que ya se de donde viene el problema, me ha vuelto a salir en una pantalla, y es porque creo 3 view que están dentro de otra view que esta dentro de la view principal, esta cadena de views una dentro de otra creo que es la culpable... estoy reduciendo su número. Te iré informando.

Comment: Ummm... sería un comportamiento extraño. ¿hay imágenes?si las hay, ¿las cargas de local?

Comment: Al final, he conseguido quitar el lag rehaciendo la app desde una plantilla vacia. Me ha hecho sudar, pues tambien me ha pasado alguna cosa rara con el autolayout en el storyboard, pero al fin y al cabo solucionado. Gracias de todas formas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final, he conseguido quitar el lag rehaciendo la app desde una plantilla vacia. Me ha hecho sudar, pues tambien me ha pasado alguna cosa rara con el autolayout en el storyboard, pero al fin y al cabo solucionado. Gracias de todas formas.

Answer (score 0):

A mi parecer, si estas cargando muchos datos que están directos en la APP, obviamente se te va a ralentizar, imágenes sobre todo.
No tengo la seguridad de si lo estas probando en tu dispositivo o solo en el emulador.

Comment: Hola Aldo, no cargo casi datos, es lo que me extraña, incluso he probado a quitar la imagen del launchScreen y de la primera pantalla. Lo he probado tanto en el simulador como en el dispositivo, siempre con el mismo problema.

Tengo otra app parecida con mas datos que no tiene el problema. La única diferencia es que la otra la empece con la plantilla vacia y esta con la de Core Data.

Estoy pensando en volver a hacer la app desde 0, pero el problema es que ya la tengo en la appStore. No se si puedo empezar un nuevo proyecto desde 0 y subirlo como una actualización de la actual.

Answer (score 0):

¿Ya probaste usando imagenes con menor peso? En ocaciones el lag en las aplicaciones se debe a que las imágenes (iconos) que se usan en ellas son pesados y le lleva más tiempo a la aplicación cargar dicha imagen, intenta usar imagenes que pesen menos, o tambien puedes cambiar el formato, quizás usas imagenes `.png`, trata usando `.jpg`.

Comment: Al final lo soluciones, rehaciendo la app desde cero, con el mismo código, imagenes, etc... Algo que se generó mal al utilizar la plantilla o asi...

Gracias de todas formas.